# Exit jquery .each loop after

Tags: jquery

I have a list of links I open by clicking a button:

```
$(document).on('click', '.openall', function() {
    $(".hasreviews a").each(function() {
        var url = $(this).text();
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    })
});
```

This will open all links I have in new tabs. This works fine when I have like 10-20 links. Sometimes I have 50 links and my browser freezes. Is there a way to stop clicking links after 15 urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a common class on each link to re-encounter the button click again and again:

```
$(document).on('click', '.openall', function() {
  $(".hasreviews a.not-clicked").each(function(index, value) {
    if (4 > index) {
      var url = $(this).text();
      $(this).removeClass('not-clicked');
      window.open(url, '_blank');

    }
  })
});
```

Working snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/xqrfpz61/ (allow block-popup first option while running it)

**Note:** Also use `$(this).attr('href')` rather than `$(this).text();`. A more accurate way to work